# Sitecore- Email campaign link redirect issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms, sitecore-ecm

I have multiple sites under single sitecore and I have configured "EmailCampaigh Message Root" for each sites.

I have created a Newsletter template with a link to this website

I dispatched the email

I received the email and When I click on the link its showing "Document not found" page

I made some changes in SiteDefinition.Config but doesnt work.

Do anyone have idea about how to configure ECM for multiple sites.

Thanks

Comment: I've configured ECM to work the way you have it.  Couple of clarification questions: Which version of ECM and Sitecore?  Did you follow the configuration instructions from the [Administrators and Developer's Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/ecm/22/ecm_administrator_and_developer_guide_22-a4.pdf)?  Are you using a 'test dispatch' or actually dispatching the email?

Comment: This issue is resolved. Actually I have created new config file for site configuration. But for some reason ECM is targeting sites only on SiteDefinition.Config.

Answer (score 0):

I see you resolved the issue allready, but for future readers:
I had the same problem (Sitecore 6.6, ECM 1.2.0):

If your 'Rendering.SiteResolving' is set to 'true', then Sitecore will try to use the subdomain if possible, making your internal links use the subdomain defined as hostName in SiteDefinition.config (or web.config if you keep your site-definitions there).

Example: If you insert an internal link to sitecore/Content/Website/somesite, in the newsletter this link should become

```
http://yourdomain.com/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_url=/somesite?...
```

But if you have a site-definition with hostName="somesite", then the link will become

```
http://yourdomain.com/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_url=http://somesite.yourdomain.com?....
```

If you inspect the class Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.EmailResponse, that sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx inherits from, you see this:

```
string link = Context.Request.QueryString["ec_url"];
...
bool isInternal = link.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !link.StartsWith("//", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

So your subdomain-link is not accepted as internal anymore - and then this happens:

```
if (!isInternal && !ExternalLinks.IsLinkRegistered(message, link))
    throw new EmailCampaignException("The unregistered external link: " + link + " detected.");
```

You can fix this easily by changing the siteresolving-setting to false. For me this was out of the question for several reasons, so here is what I did - and please tell me if you have better approach:
I let RedirectUrlPage.aspx inherit from a custom class, that called a custom EmailReponse. Here I changed the condition to:

```
bool isInternal = (link.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !link.StartsWith("//", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) || link.IndexOf("yourdomain") > -1;
```

This works!
Off course the hard-coded domain name should be replaced by something like HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host, but I did not test exactly that in production yet - will do in next deploy.